# Check if composer is installed and run from bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell, composer-php

I'm trying to create a `install.sh` script that checks if all my dependencies are installed and then triggers the dependencies scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

phpValidation() {
    if hash php 2>/dev/null; then
        echo 'we have php'
    else
        echo 'no php'
    fi
}

composerValidation() {
    if type -t composer ; then #this part does not work
        echo 'we have composer'
    else
        echo 'no composer?!'
    fi
}
```

It works fine for `php` and `yarn`, but because composer is an alias it does not get trigged through the script.

How can I check if composer is installed and then trigger it?

Comment: I would let the user config the cmd (path) used to trigger composer.

Comment: Just invoke composer and handle the case that it fails.

Answer (score 3):

I found a pretty good script [here](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash/blob/master/scripts/composer.sh) and modified it to fit my needs.

Here is my simplified version I came up with in the end:

```
//  Check for composer
composer -v > /dev/null 2>&1
COMPOSER=$?
if [[ $COMPOSER -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo 'Composer is not installed'
else
    echo 'Composer is installed'
fi
```

Comment: and this works because COMPOSER is a environment variable holding what you just put in above ?